# Prove a matrix is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

To show that a matrix is not diagonalizable, I would just have to show that there are no eigenvalues present in the matrix.

---

So, for example, if I want to prove that

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

is not diagonalizable - would I say that it is since the tr(A) does not form any eigenvalues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the charactersitic polynomial, which is in this case equal to $x^{2}+1$. Assuming you are working in $\mathbf{R}$ this polynomial has no real roots, and hence A has no eigenvalues so A is not diagonalisable.

Comment: However having solutions to the characteristic polynomial does not mean that it must be diagonalizable. For instance if you are on $\mathbb{C}$ the characteristic polynomial will always have N zeros, but it may have any number of eigenvalues.

Comment: if the problem does not specify working in R, then should I test the imaginary solution +-i?

Comment: If you're working in $\mathbf{C}$ then your matrix is diagonalisable.

Answer (score 0):

If A (2x2) is diagonalizable, then there must be enough eigenspaces of total size dim(R^2)=2, in other words the sum of the total vectors in all eigenspaces must span R^2.

So in your case, solve for the eigenvalues then their respective eigenspaces. If you get enough a total of 2 vectors across all the eigenspaces, then A is diagonalizable.

Comment: are _eigenspaces_ synonymous with the subspace formed by eigenvectors, and/or the basis formed by the eigenvectors?

Comment: Yea they are Ian, an eigenspace is defined as follows: $E_{\lambda} = ker\{A-\lambda I_n\}$